# Time Control for Bullet, Blitz and Standard

Tags: time-control

Does anyone know the function which dictates which three of these time-control categories any particular game would fall under?  For example, I know that a 3 0 is the quickest blitz game that can be played but I would be unsure whether or not a 2 3 (2 minutes on each persons clock with 3 second increments added) would be blitz or bullet.  I'm assuming there is a fairly simplistic formula I could plug these metrics into for a definitive answer but I have yet to stumble upon it.

Thanks ^_^

Comment: Are you talking about some particular online chess server? From the fact that you say "standard" instead of "rapid" or "classical" I am guessing that you might be. If you are, please tell us which it is.

Comment: Yeah, I think he is referring to chess.com, which uses these terms. Other synonymous terms used are lightning, active, rapid, classical....

Comment: I figured they were all based on either FIDE or USCF designations but yes I was talking about chess.com and ICC servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such globally accepted formula. Time controls are defined only by their formal definitions (as unhelpful as that sounds). Any further descriptive language, like "blitz" or "lightning" or "bullet", while they carry certain conventional connotations, do not have objective criteria. However, certain organizations may define these terms concretely within their own domains.

---

### USCF

The USCF [defines](http://www.uschess.org/docs/gov/reports/RulebookChanges.pdf) three time-control zones: *Regular*, *Quick*, and *Blitz*. Different sets of time controls fall into one (or more--it is possible for a game to count as *both* Regular and Quick, in which case the player's ratings in both categories are affected) of these categories. Determining the category is simple: calculate the [estimated] *total playing time* (`TPT_U`) as:

```
TPT_U = Minutes + SecondsPerIncrement
```

The `TPT_U` is then slotted into a zone as follows:

```
TPT_U > 65: Regular
30 ≤ TPT_U ≤ 65: Regular AND Quick
10 < TPT_U < 30: Quick
5 ≤ TPT_U ≤ 10: Blitz
```

---

### FIDE

FIDE [defines](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article) (as far as I can tell) two time-control zones beyond the [standard FIDE time control](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=39&view=category): *Rapid* and *Blitz*. To determine which of these zones a time control falls within, calculate the [estimated] *total playing time* (`TPT_F`) as:

```
TPT_F = Minutes + SecondsPerIncrement
```

The `TPT_F` is then slotted into a zone as follows:

```
10 < TPT_F < 60: Rapid
TPT_F ≤ 10: Blitz
```

---

### CHESS.COM

Chess.com [defines](https://support.chess.com/customer/portal/articles/1444851-why-are-there-three-different-ratings-in-live-chess-) three time-control zones: *Standard*, *Blitz*, and *Bullet*. To determine which of these zones a time control falls within, calculate the [estimated] *total playing time* in minutes (`TPT_C`) as:

```
TPT_C = Minutes + 2/3*SecondsPerIncrement
```

This assumes a forty-move game and is derived from the following expression (multiply the increment in seconds by forty, then convert to minutes):

```
TPT_C = Minutes + (40 * SecondsPerIncrement / 60)
```

The `TPT_C` is then slotted into a zone as follows*:

```
15 ≤ TPT_C: Standard
3 ≤ TPT_C < 15: Blitz
TPT_C < 3: Bullet
```

*I've had to extrapolate here, as the [definition](https://support.chess.com/customer/portal/articles/1444851-why-are-there-three-different-ratings-in-live-chess-) actually appears to leave a gap between 14 and 15 minutes. I've filled this gap in the manner I considered most likely to be accurate.

---

### Examples

```
Base | Incr | TPT_U | TPT_F | TPT_C | USCF  | FIDE  | CHESS.COM
-----|------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|----------
 2   | 1    | 3     | 3     | 2.667 | N/A   | Blitz | Bullet
 3   | 0    | 3     | 3     | 3     | N/A   | Blitz | Blitz
 3   | 2    | 5     | 5     | 4.333 | Blitz | Blitz | Blitz
 5   | 0    | 5     | 5     | 5     | Blitz | Blitz | Blitz
 10  | 0    | 10    | 10    | 10    | Blitz | Blitz | Blitz
 10  | 1    | 11    | 11    | 10.67 | Quick | Rapid | Blitz
 14  | 3    | 17    | 17    | 16    | Quick | Rapid | Standard
```

Comment: So is TPT re-evaluated at the end of the game once the total amount of moves are known or are the ratings to be affected locked in and decided at the start regardless of actual TPT?

Comment: `TPT` is an estimation; it is the same for all games using the given time control. Essentially it assumes that each player makes 60 moves (by adding seconds to minutes as though they shared a unit: equivalent to `B minutes + 60*I seconds`). I've just added some examples that may clear it up for you.

Comment: Ah, I understand, that's interesting that some assume total moves as 40 and others 60 and that's where some of the inconsistency comes from

Comment: I think 60 moves is too much, 40 moves is closer to the truth. OFcourse, TPT makes everything simpler.

Comment: @CognisMantis I don't claim that these are somehow objectively "correct" definitions (in fact I claim the exact opposite at the start of the answer); just that this is how FIDE and USCF define these time control labels.

Comment: The inconsistency of TPT. (2,1)=3. The same value for (3,0)=3 In reality, (3,0) is slightly longer than (2,1), and since (3,0) is the boundary, (2,1) would be considered blitz. Chess.com seems to use a formula closer to mine since (2,1) is bullet for them.

Comment: yeah, I knew that. Sorry if I made it seem that I was attacking you or something. Just showing that Fide and USCF does not use the most precise formula since the average move per game is close to 40.

Comment: @CognisMantis No worries, though I'm still doubtful that "precision" is even a meaningful concept here. After all, they're just creating a definition for a locally-applicable term: it doesn't really matter *what* the definition is, so long as it is *defined*. I'd guess that short time control games probably average less than 40 moves anyway :-)

Comment: @CognisMantis The formula you guessed for chess.com is actually spot-on (some factoring aside). I found their documentation and added a section covering it.

Comment: great minds think alike

Comment: Whoever downvoted; please tell me why--if there is something incorrect or misleading in my answer, I need to know what it is in order to fix it!

Comment: I up voted that was like a perfect answer, that being said, what should I do to get more up votes on my question, it seemed like a good one?

Comment: @maxwell That's really a question for [meta](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/), but the real answer is probably "wait".

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is a simple formula. It is similar to the paradox between defining heaps of sand or grains of sand. It is difficult to draw the line precisely. If a formula is necessary, I would define it by how much time is used. 
Assuming that the barriers between blitz and bullet(lightning) is 3 0. 
A time control can be written as (x,y), for example, (3,0) is the quickest time control for blitz. 
Let F(x,y)=2x+(4/3)y. 
The 4/3 was created by the expected time used in a game that last 40 moves(supposedly the average length of a game).
 F(2,3)=2(2)+(4/3)(3)=4+4=8 Therefore, (2,3) is blitz because it is greater than the boundary defined by F(3,0)=2(3)+0=6
The same can be done for standard chess, but a boundary must be specified.

Answer (score 0):

As if this weren't confusing enough, on ICC there are ratings for

- bullet
- blitz
- standard
- 1-minute
- 3-minute
- 5-minute
- 15-minute
- 25-minute

To make matters worse, a game with any of the time controls of 5 minutes or greater can be either in that TC category, or simply a Standard TC game.

So, this seems to be a matter of personal taste at a number of the websites, rather than a case of adhering to FIDE, USCF or any other rules.

By the way, there's also allowable variation in the USCF time controls definitions of regular time controls, but the basic criteria are these (for regular rated games):

1. The duration of the first time-control must be at least 30 minutes for each player.(However, see (3) below for an exception.)
2. If a non-sudden death control is used, the rate of play must be equal to or slower than an average of 60 moves per hour.
3. Rule 5Fa is an option that allows the TD to shorten the basic time control in minutes by the delay in seconds for games using a digital clock with delay. When this option is mandated, the initial control, not the shortened control will govern under which system the event is rated. A G/30 ( 5 second delay) with the control shortened to G/25 for the games using a delay will still be rated in the regular system.
4. Any secondary controls must be at least 30 minutes.

For FIDE, this is the information I use (a summary taken from USCF reference materials):

1.0 Rate of Play

For a game to be rated each player must have a minimum of two hours in which to complete all the moves, *assuming the game lasts 60 moves*. Examples of ways this can be achieved follow.

a. The rate of play must not exceed 23 moves per hour at any stage.

b. All the moves in two hours.

c. 40 moves in two hours followed by all the moves in 30 minutes.

d. All the moves in 100 minutes initially, but each time a player makes a move an additional 30 seconds is added to the clock time.

Note that these are minimum conditions; any time control system that a TD implements that is more generous than these conditions require automatically satisfies the regular rating criteria.